# Can anyone recommend a good PHP HTML cleanser?

Tags: php, html, data-cleaning

Pretty self explanatory, I want to allow html from users to be displayed on a web page.

Ideally it should allow elements like `<p><strong><em><a><ul><li>` while disallowing ids, classes, `<script>`, `<style>`, inline javascript and so on. Ensuring HTML validity is a strong plus. HTML (as opposed to XHTML, or at least being able to choose) would be nice also.

Of course, I could use something like MarkDown, but i'd prefer a system that didn't require users to learn new skills if possible.

Sorry if this question is a duplicate, I did check first but found nothing. A quick google obviously had some results, but I only have the developers word that they are any good (i.e. secure).

Free/Open source solutions preferred.

Comment: Related, maybe useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859294/keep-user-generated-content-from-breaking-layout/5859414

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i'd prefer a system that didn't require users to learn new skills if possible.

Assuming your users know basic html?

I use [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), and no complaints so far.